# How to permute C# Tuple Items?

Tags: c#, tuples, permutation, combinatorics

How to permute a tuple containing several string items?

Comment: The question is about if it's possible at all (having n-item tuple)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Tuple`, manually I'm afraid. So:

```
var tuple = new Tuple<string, string, string>("a", "b", "c");
var combination_1 = String.Concat(tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2, tuple.Item3);
var combination_2 = String.Concat(tuple.Item1, tuple.Item3, tuple.Item2);
var combination_3 = String.Concat(tuple.Item2, tuple.Item1, tuple.Item3);
var combination_4 = String.Concat(tuple.Item2, tuple.Item3, tuple.Item1);
var combination_5 = String.Concat(tuple.Item3, tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2);
var combination_6 = String.Concat(tuple.Item3, tuple.Item2, tuple.Item1);
```

Using modified Eric Liperts extension method, you could do something like this:

*Extension method:*

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
{
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };

    return sequences.Aggregate
        ( emptyProduct, (accumulator, sequence) =>
            from accseq in accumulator
            from item in sequence
            where !accseq.Contains(item)
            select accseq.Concat(new[] { item })
        );
}
```

*Use case:*

```
var array = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, array.Length).Select(_ => array).CartesianProduct();

// Print results
foreach (var item in result)
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join("", item));
```

If you ever wish to get *all* permutations including *"aaa"*, *"aab"* etc. simply remove

`where !accseq.Contains(item)` from extension method.

Comment: Also this way: `string[] stringArray = {tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2, ... tuple.ItemN};` (unpacking tuple object first)

Comment: @AndrejsIgumenovs yeah, that's right. You could get items out of tuple into array and use the same extension method.

Answer (score 2):

Because `"6"`is a very small number, it is most efficient to just write it down:

```
tupple1 = a,b,c
tupple2 = a,c,b
...
```

You can't create a program in shorter time.

If you are interested in a more genral solution however, see one of the plenty links on SO, example : [Permutation algorithms in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168269/permutation-algorithms-in-c-sharp?rq=1)

Comment: Well, if I have one more `string d`, then the number would be 24.

Comment: Well, then this is a different question

Comment: Should I use LINQ then?

Comment: @AndrejsIgumenovs, if you want help creating the `n!` permutations for an `n` element tuple, then please post a question asking for that and  showing what you have achieved so far. As it stands, this is a good answer to your current bad question.

Comment: Please check the links in the right column "Related". You'll find plenty answers