# Autoincrement Alphabets in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to use the code after searching too much in google for alphabet increment. My logic is;

```
string result = char.ConvertFromUtf32(97 + index1 % 26) + result
```

The code is working fine till A to Z. However, i want the next letter to appear after Z as AA in one click. Then AB till ZZZZZ.

Answer (score 0):

You should just have a number and increment it normally but then convert it to base 26, it will naturally give the increments from A thru to ZZZZ.

Have a look at this other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559122/convert-base-27-or-base-x-to-base-10-in-c) for a C# solution that allows base 10 to base 26 conversion.